# Is there a proof that the power set of a countable sample space supports a probability measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

When I typed my question the following link came up in the 'similar questions' list and I thought great, there's an answer to my question.

[Why can a probability measure be defined over power set of countable sample space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522714/why-can-a-probability-measure-be-defined-over-power-set-of-countable-sample-spac)

However, the answers and comments offered did not answer (or even address) @majmun's question at all, at least not from my perspective, so I'm posting my question: is there a proof that the power set of a countable sample space will support a $\textbf{probability}$ measure? Not a Dirac point measure, not a counting measure, a probability measure.

Comment: If the set is ${\mathbb N}$ you can let the measure of $\{k\}$ be ${1 \over 2^k}$ and then extend by countable additivity.

Comment: The Dirac measure *is* a probability measure. So what are you asking exactly? Do you have a clear understanding of what it means to be a probability measure? Do you want to know why there will be a probability measure with certain properties, or subject to certain conditions? If so, you should say what they are.

Comment: Perhaps you have read something along the lines of "if $\Omega$ is countable, then probability measures just correspond to mass functions, so by convention take $\mathcal F = \mathcal P(\Omega)$...". This is not the same fact as "powersets of countable sets always support some probability measure" - rather you can state this fact as "a probability measure on any $\sigma$-algebra on a countable set always extends to the powerset". [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2793083/473276) seems relevant..

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen. Point taken on the Dirac measure.  The link was interesting.